# Natural isomorphism between the ranges of $T$ and $T^*$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

One way to prove the equality of row and column rank is to show that $\text{null}(T^*)=\text{annihilator}(\text{range}\; T)$ and then to invoke the rank-nullity theorem and a theorem about the dimension of annihilators. But this makes the result look like a numerical coincidence. I was wondering if there is a way to construct a natural isomorphism between $\text{range}(T)$ and $\text{range}(T^*)$?

Comment: No because this would imply a natural isomorphism between any vector space $V$ and its dual $V*$.